# Routing eth network packets over ppp connection

Tags: linux, networking, router, routing, ppp

I have 2 machines with a ppp connection over serial between them. They are also connected to seperate LANs on their ethernet interfaces. I want to be able to have communication between these two ethernet networks.

These networks may or may not be in different subnets. All IPs are statically assigned, so no DHCP is involved.

A crude topology is as follows;

```
          eth        ppp(tty)       eth
network1 <----> box1 <-----> box2 <-----> network2
```

Can this be achieved with simple  `ip route` commands?

Comment: Can you clarify "These networks may or may not be in different subnets"?

Comment: @grawity, essentially means that no constraint over this is defined at the moment. If this is an architectural decision that is needed to be made beforehand, we can assume whichever makes the most sense or simplifies the solution. I am not the most educated in these topics, so sorry if this makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, I get the "may or may not be" part. Could you clarify how you define "subnets"? Do you mean that network1 and network2 should be able to share one IP address prefix? (Normally "two networks" would mean two subnets and two IP prefixes practically by definition.) Do you need to send IP broadcasts, and/or non-IP traffic, through the link?

Comment: I see, sorry :) So these two networks are normally private networks, managed by the same people. So technically they should be able to share the same subnet prefix when they are not connected. In my application, when needed they should be able to communicate. Stuff like IP conflicts are a non-issue since both networks are managed by the same people. If possible, what I want is to have it operate as if these two networks were plugged into a regular router and have transparent communication between them.

Comment: As far as I can tell at the moment, this link will be used strictly for IP based communication. But it would be nice if you could help with what non-IP traffic may be needed. Like I said, if having two subnets and two IP prefixes are a must, we can assume that it is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best if net1 and net2 act as independent subnets, with different IP address prefixes and separate broadcast domains.

In this case, with two interfaces in each 'box', what you have is practically **the simplest kind of an IP router.** (Just think of the 'ppp' interface as a third network connecting the two routers, with its own private IP prefix.)

- Each router already knows how to reach directly connected networks (it gets this information from the "subnet mask" or "prefix length" when you configure IP addresses on interfaces). They still need routes for distant networks.
- On box 1, add a route to <network2> via <IP address of box2.ppp>.
- On box 2, add a route to <network1> via <IP address of box1.ppp>.

(It's also possible to leave the ppp interfaces unnumbered and configure routes via the interface instead, e.g. using the `dev ppp0` keyword instead of `via <addr>` on Linux. It's probably not recommended.)

But more importantly, the devices *within* those networks must know that they should be using box1 and box2 as their gateways to the opposite network. (They don't have to use box1 and box2 as *default gateways*, however. If the two networks already have their own default gateways, configure the routes via box1/box2 there instead.)

---

If the link between net1 and net2 must be transparent at Ethernet layer (e.g. if you're sending non-IP traffic), then the devices cannot be routers – they need to act as *bridges*. Configuring a bridge between two interfaces is easy; the problem, however, is that "regular" PPP only carries network layer traffic and not raw Ethernet frames.

So for bridging you'd need either a special PPP mode for Ethernet; or maybe MPLS over PPP (which I'm sure exists); or create a tunnel such as "gretap" or "erspan" *on top* of IP networking (which has some overhead). All options are possible, but require knowing what is supported by box1&box2 – unlike routing, which is the core feature of a router.

Comment: I have added the routing rules in the box1/box2. I can ping one machines ethernet NIC from the other machine. But I cannot ping the ethernet NIC of a box from a machine in the opposite network. I have set the gateway in that machine aswell. For example a machine in `10.0.0.0/24` network has a routing rule like `192.168.1.0/24 via 10.0.0.144 dev em1` where `192.168.1.0/24` is the other network and `10.0.0.144` is the gateway in its own network.

Comment: Use `tcpdump -ni <dev>` on all hops (every interface along the path) to make sure the packets arrive.

Comment: Ok, I have enabled ip forwarding with sysctl and it seems to be working now. I will try more scenarios.

Comment: Is an additional rule needed for forwarding packets to actual ethernet networks? Pinging ethernet NICs of box1/box2 works but pinging devices across networks does not.

Comment: Usually no. Do you see the ping packets on the ethernet interface that is supposed to output the packet?

Comment: Ping packets reach the destination, i do see them in wireshark. But no response is generated.

Comment: There are bunch of Destination Unreachable ICMP packets going around in the network. All from ppp ip of the box in the network.

Comment: Ok, turning of all firewalls in the host machines solved the issue. Thank you!